# Generate selectable folder and files from set of path

Tags: xcode, macos

I am using xcode and I need to generate a list of folders/files (which can be selected with a check box) from a catalog which is in text file (`program.txt`) format.

The program.txt file contain the path mentioned below:

```
2282_program_18-Oct-09_Cam1/
2282_program_18-Oct-09_Cam1/BRM90001_01.MP4
2282_program_18-Oct-09_Cam1/BRM90001_02.MP4
2282_program_18-Oct-09_Cam21/
2282_program_18-Oct-09_Cam1/BRM90002_01.MP4
2282_program_18-Oct-09_Cam1/BRM90002_02.MP4
```

Comment: What language are you programming in? Xcode isn't a language, it's an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file using the `NSString` method [`-stringWithContentsOfURL:usedEncoding:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html). Next, you can separate it by paragraph as described in the section of the `NSString` documentation named [Separating a String "By Paragraph"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/stringsParagraphBreaks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005016-SW1).

Once you've done that, you'll probably want to create an [`NSTableView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/Introduction/Introduction.html) that has one column with the file path in it, and another column with checkboxes in them.

Comment: is there any way to have folder icon with checkboxes insted of path in the tabel

Comment: Sure. You can put whatever you want in the table. Look up `NSTableView` and see how to set the cell type to an icon instead of a string.